# Relative Path not working in powershell when passing parameters to Pickles Cmdlet / Nuget

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, nuget, relative-path, solution

I'm using the pickles NuGet package to produce DHTML feature file webpages so that they can be published on an intranet site. I was using a relative path to do this from inside the Pack age Manager Console in VS2012:-

```
PM> Pickle-Features -FeatureDirectory .\FIX_SpecflowTests\Specs -OutputDirectory .\FIX_SpecflowTests\Pickles -SystemUnderTestName FIX_SpecflowTests -DocumentationFormat DHTML -TestResultsFile .\FIX_SpecflowTests\bin\Debug\TestResult.xml
```

which produced this output:-

```
Pickles v.0.13.1.0

Generating documentation based on the following parameters
----------------------------------------------------------
Feature Directory         : C:\svn\local\BakeryDemoTest\trunk\AllBakeryDemoTestProjects\FIX_SpecflowTests\Specs
Output Directory          : C:\svn\local\BakeryDemoTest\trunk\AllBakeryDemoTestProjects\FIX_SpecflowTests\Pickles
Project Name              : FIX_SpecflowTests
Project Version           : 
Language                  : 
Incorporate Test Results? : Yes
Test Result Format        : NUnit
Test Result File          : C:\svn\local\BakeryDemoTest\trunk\AllBakeryDemoTestProjects\FIX_SpecflowTests\bin\Debug\TestResult.xml
Pickles completed successfully
PM>
```

Lovely! However, since installing Update 4 for Visual Studio and an update for Nuget, the relative path has stopped working, so I get this output instead:-

```
Pickles v.0.13.1.0

Generating documentation based on the following parameters
----------------------------------------------------------
Feature Directory         : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\FIX_SpecflowTests\Specs
Output Directory          : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\FIX_SpecflowTests\Pickles
Project Name              : FIX_SpecflowTests
Project Version           : 
Language                  : 
Incorporate Test Results? : Yes
Test Result Format        : NUnit
Test Result File          : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\FIX_SpecflowTests\bin\Debug\TestResult.xml
Pickle-Features : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\FIX_SpecflowTests\Specs'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Pickle-Features <<<<  -FeatureDirectory .\FIX_SpecflowTests\Specs -OutputDirectory .\FIX_SpecflowTests\Pickles -SystemUnderTestName FIX_SpecflowTests -DocumentationFormat DHTML -TestResultsFile .\FIX_SpecflowTests\bin\Debug\TestResult.xml
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Pickle-Features], DirectoryNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,PicklesDoc.Pickles.PowerShell.Pickle_Features

PM>
```

As you can see, the base path that is being used is inside the VS2012 installation directory, and not the solution directory. Does anyone know how to correctly set the "base" path for package manager to work out relative paths from?

Eventually I want to run this as a Powershell script from outside VS2012, but I think I need to get it working from Package Manager first!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't exactly find an answer to this, but I did find a workaround - just implementing the powershell script. I used a snippet from [Run NUnit tests from powershell](https://coderwall.com/p/0ycecq) as a guide to do this - I'll summarise here what I actually did:-

1. get the current directory and store it  (assume I'm in a project directory)
2. and go up a level and store this (assume I'm now in the solution directory)
3. set my output folder (I'm only doing this on the release build, not debug)
4. run tests via nunit
5. run pickle
6. run the specflow report

```
    $scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    $dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
    cd $dir 
    cd ../
    $SolutionDir = Get-Location
    $OutDir = "$dir\bin\Release"
    $nunit = "$SolutionDir\packages\NUnit.Runners.2.6.3\tools\nunit-console.exe"

    $tests = (Get-ChildItem $OutDir -Recurse -Include *Tests.dll)

    & $nunit /noshadow /framework:"net-4.5" /xml:"$OutDir\TestResult.xml" $tests "/out:$OutDir\TestResult.txt"

    Write-host "My package is in $SolutionDir/packages\Pickles.0.13.1.0\tools\PicklesDoc.Pickles.PowerShell.dll"
    Import-Module $SolutionDir/packages\Pickles.0.13.1.0\tools\PicklesDoc.Pickles.PowerShell.dll
    Pickle-Features -FeatureDirectory $dir\Specs -OutputDirectory $dir\Pickles -SystemUnderTestName FIX_SpecflowTests -DocumentationFormat DHTML -TestResultsFile $dir\bin\Release\TestResult.xml

    cd $dir
    $specflowReporter = "$SolutionDir\packages\SpecFlow.1.9.0\tools\specflow.exe"
    $proj = "FIX_SpecflowTests.csproj"
    $xml = "$OutDir\TestResult.xml"

    & $specflowReporter nunitexecutionreport $proj /xmlTestResult:"$xml" /out:"$OutDir\TestResult.html"
```

Comment: If anyone does know how to answer the original question of how to set where package manager works out it's base path for relative paths I'd still appreciate an answer!